# How to call a different state on second button click?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I want to load a different state on my second button click.
How can I do it in expression blend 3/silverlight3?

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense.  "load a different state"? Please use a lot more words to describe what you want to do.

Comment: This is what I want to do. I have 3 buttons corresponding to 3 containers which will hold different data. When I click button 1 the 1st container will appear same goes to the other 2. I used GoToState behavior in this case and it worked. What I want to do next is I can click all the three buttons simultaneously which will show me all the three containers. And when I click those buttons again the corresponding containers will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

VisualStateManager.GoToState(ControlName, "StateName", true);